# android class loading, apache http client library

Tags: android, httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x

i'm trying to do a HTTP POST to a URL. the backend requires a text field and a file. i'm using Android 4.1 (minSdkVersion = 8, targetSdkVersion = 15). i've seen a lot of examples on how to do this operation on android ([Concise example of file upload via Java lib Apache Commons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698059/concise-example-of-file-upload-via-java-lib-apache-commons)). however, i noticed that the PostMethod does not exist with the version of apache httpclient that comes with Android 4.1. my questions are as follows.

- which version of apache httpclient comes with Android 4.1?
- if i download the latest version of httpclient (v4.2.1), do i simply just copy/paste the jars into my /libs directory?
- how does android do class loading? how does android know that i'm using the newer httpclient and not what's in android.jar?
- does anyone know if the apache httpclient jars simply work "out-of-the-box" with android apps?

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

- http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpPost.html
- if using the same namespace the jar may or may not take the precedence (avoid it)
- you should refactor and change the namespace
- I never uploaded a file need to look at the api

Comment: look at this example, http://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2011/01/29/android-image-upload-activity/ you need httpmime